# Angular Backend Error Over SSL Certificate (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: angular, ssl

I have an Angular 8 application working fine on http.

I just installed a letsencrypt cetificate running "certbot --apache". The certificate is valid and I can see the safety lock on my domain now.

After fixing the environment issue that came up after installing the certificate,

```
apiUrl: 'https://app.xyz.com:8080'
```

I got a new error now (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) indicating that backend can´t see the certificate running on front end and can´t handle a https connection.

How do I "pass" the certificate I just created to backend so both can comunicate properly?
Or, do I need to install a second SSL Certificate on Back End?

Answer (score 0):

After I got some help outside from Stackoverflow, I got it right.

For anyone from the future who is facing the same problem, here is what I did.
I created another port on my backend server (Node.js) like so:

```
//Server
const https = require("https");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var app_https = express();
var cors = require('cors');
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(express.json(), cors());
app_https.use(express.json(), cors());

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('../src/assets/keys/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../src/assets/keys/cert.pem')
};
app_https = https.createServer(options, app);

//PORT ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
const port = process.env.PORT;

app_https.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port localhost:${port}`));
This was enough to access "https://www.xyzabcpqr.com:port/api/" and put it back 
together.
```